# Google maps api show images from DB

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I have the following data that come from an ajax call:

```
data: [
    rest1: {
        latlng: ["40.7143528","-74.0059731"],
        link: "restaurant1.jpg"
    },
    rest2: {
        latlng: ["40.82148067","-74.35135579"],
        link: "restaurant2.jpg"
    }
]
```

How can I show the images in my map in their specific coordinates? I know how to do it using marker and infowindow

Add a marker and then add the image in the infowindow.

But how I can show the image in the place of the marker? Without infowindow

Comment: Make the image your marker icon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose you have stored the address of the picture in a variable `address` and the position of the marker in a variable `position`. Then, your code should looks like this:

```
  var beachMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: position,
    map: map,
    icon: address
  });
```

So, when you get your json file, you may first `parse` it like this:

```
data = JSON.parse (data);
```

Then, you can use the data like this:

```
  var beachMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: {data.rest1.latlng[0], data.rest1.latlng[1]},
    map: map,
    icon: data.rest1.link
  });
```

Please consult the [google documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/markers?hl=en).

*Tell me if you have some comments.*